# How to create immutable class with mutable member variable(s)?

Tags: java, immutability

Suppose I have a Customer class which have a reference of Address Class, we can make objects of Customer class by making member variable private final blah blah.... my question is this address class is mutable with getters and setters which has its reference in Customer class, now how can we make Customer class immutable? Does making this Address reference in customer class suffice to make it an immutable class(objects of customer class immutable) Could someone explain?

Now in the scenario how do we make objects of Customer class immutable? and how the relationship between Customer and Address is shown in the memory?Can somebody answer this please?

```
public final class Customer{
    private final String name;
    private final Address address;

    public Customer(String name, Address address){
        this.name=name;
        this.address= address;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return this.name;
    }
```

}

```
public class Address{
 private String streetName;
 private Long pincode;

 public void setStreeName(String streetName){
    this.streetName = streetName;
}

 public void setPincode(long pincode){
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

public String getStreetName(){
   return this.streeName;
}

public long getPincode(){
   return this.pincode;
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the all setters in `Customer` and `Address`, and make all fields `final`.

Comment: You should tried to be more specific, and you could even add a small code to illustrate your question

Comment: Please elaborate the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In the customer class above where the other data types are primitive(immutable), whereas the Address class is not, so in the getter method of Address reference we should return a new address object with properties similar to Address reference in customer class.